# How to get Spearman R2 value using multiple linear regression

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, linear-regression

The R2 obtained from a linear regression is the Pearson correlation coefficient. However, I am wondering if I could get Spearman rank coefficient instead of Pearson in a linear regression.

I would be especially interested to get it using R with the package leaps:

```
library(leaps)  
#Plotting function  plot.regsubsets2 <- 
    function (x, labels = obj$xnames, main = NULL, scale = c("bic", 
                "Cp", "adjr2", "r2"), col = gray(seq(0, 0.9, length = 10)), 
                ...) 
            {
                obj <- x
                lsum <- summary(obj)
                par(mar = c(7, 5, 6, 3) + 0.1)
                nmodels <- length(lsum$rsq)
                np <- obj$np
                propscale <- FALSE
                sscale <- pmatch(scale[1], c("bic", "Cp", "adjr2", "r2"), 
                    nomatch = 0)
                if (sscale == 0) 
                    stop(paste("Unrecognised scale=", scale))
                if (propscale) 
                    stop(paste("Proportional scaling only for probabilities"))
                yscale <- switch(sscale, lsum$bic, lsum$cp, lsum$adjr2, lsum$rsq)
                up <- switch(sscale, -1, -1, 1, 1)
                index <- order(yscale * up)
                colorscale <- switch(sscale, yscale, yscale, -log(pmax(yscale, 
                    1e-04)), -log(pmax(yscale, 1e-04)))
                image(z = t(ifelse(lsum$which[index, ], colorscale[index], 
                    NA + max(colorscale) * 1.5)), xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", 
                    x = (1:np), y = 1:nmodels, xlab = "", ylab = scale[1], 
                    col = col)
                laspar <- par("las")
                on.exit(par(las = laspar))
                par(las = 2)
                axis(1, at = 1:np, labels = labels, ...) # I modified this line
                axis(2, at = 1:nmodels, labels = signif(yscale[index], 2))
                if (!is.null(main)) 
                    title(main = main)
                box()
                invisible(NULL)
            }

#Leap 
leaps = regsubets(y~x1+x2+x2, data=mydf, nbest=10) 
summary(leaps) 
plot.regsubsets2(leaps, scale='r2')
```

Again, I would like if it possible to screen Spearman instead of Pearson (r2) in the plot.

Comment: you can consider posting this question cross validated forum.